# How does an individual access the Bitcoin Core repo and contribute to it in the case that GitHub boots Bitcoin Core or the individual off GitHub?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, tor, censorship-resistance

It is [not](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20227) looking like Bitcoin Core will be moving from GitHub anytime soon (unless forced to).

How does an individual access the Bitcoin Core repo and contribute to it in the case that GitHub boots Bitcoin Core or the individual off GitHub?

What should an individual do in advance to prepare for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing interesting happens if github bans bitcoin, the repository will be uploaded on a different host. Git is a decentralized application and several mirrors exist already. The contributors also have local copies of the repository so no code will be lost.

The biggest problem would be that the github issues and comments will be lost since they are a github feature (not part of the git repository).

Comment: It is unlikely the issues and comments would be lost as long as some contributors have used Andrew Chow's full GitHub downloader tool. https://github.com/achow101/github-dl

Answer (score 0):

Wladimir van der Laan posted this on Mastodon.

> My personal bitcoin Git repository, which mirrors upstream branches
> and tags is available through a TorV3 service on
> http://nxshomzlgqmwfwhcnyvbznyrybh3gotlfgis7wkv7iur2yj2rarlhiad.onion/
>
> (instructions for cloning are on the website)
>
> I'm also mirroring it to the radicle (https://radicle.xyz/) P2P code
> collaboration platform:
>
> rad:git:hwd1yreyfmyg5my7kskrsc5r33h5jr9anra9635hpncfs9f1wsk1eaf8f9w

Some additional guidance is on Wladimir's [blog](https://laanwj.github.io/2018/06/08/tor-repository.html).

Note there have been recent consensus [issues](https://consensus-health.torproject.org/) with Tor v3 addresses.